# Database takes up MUCH more disk space than I thought it would

Tags: postgresql

when i execute this request in pgadmin :

```
SELECT table_name, 
pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)::bigint) As Taille_donnees,
pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)::bigint) As Taille_totale,
pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)::bigint) As Taille_index
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '***'
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name) DESC
```

The data size is 392 kb, the index size is 136 kb, and the total size is 1216 Mb, how is that possible ? I looked at the table and there is only 350 lines, why is this table so heavy ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: What do you mean with "there is only lines"? What "lines" are you talking about? Are you maybe referring to "rows"? Then yes, a table contains only rows. Also the total relation size includes TOASTed data which is not included in `pg_relation_size()` so it might simply mean that you are storing many very large text values in the table that are stored outside of the main relation data

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT

> **pg_relation_size** Disk space used by the specified fork ('main', 'fsm', 'vm', or 'init') of the specified table or index

I suppose you wanted to use instead:

> **pg_table_size(regclass)**   Disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes (but including TOAST, free space map, and visibility
>   map)

because `pg_relation_size` does not show the (all) data size - only the *main* fork:

> **pg_relation_size(relation regclass)** Shorthand for pg_relation_size(..., 'main')

you probalby tried to apply formula:

> pg_total_relation_size accepts the OID or name of a table or toast
>   table, and returns the total on-disk space used for that table,
>   including all associated indexes. This function is equivalent to
>   pg_table_size + pg_indexes_size.

but used wrong function, because `pg_total_relation_size` has word *relation*, and yet is a sum of `pg_table_size`, not `pg_relation_size`?..